# User control Grid column width in the View/Window

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, user-controls, grid

Am having a Address user control, am using this control in all the data entry forms

Two columns

1. labels
2. text box contorls

i want to adjust the 1 column based on the view its used

[image: User control]

for example

this is one of the view where the user control is used

**Red** marked is the **View** Grid column

**Yellow** marked is the **User control** grid column

is there any way to set the yellow marked to be equal to red marked column width ??

Or is it possible to create a Dependency property and bind the width to the column, or any other smart way to resolve this issue??

[image: View where user control is used]

XAML

```
 <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>           
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="Full Name" Style="{StaticResource FormTextBlockStyle}" />
    <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Width="200" Text="" Style="{StaticResource FormTextBoxStyle}" IsEnabled="False" IsReadOnly="True" />

    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="Gender" Style="{StaticResource FormTextBlockStyle}" />
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <RadioButton x:Name="RadioGendeMale" Content="Male" />
        <RadioButton Content="Female" Margin="8,0,0,0" />
    </StackPanel>

    <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Text="Date of Birth" Style="{StaticResource FormTextBlockStyle}" />
    <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Width="200" Text="" Style="{StaticResource FormTextBoxStyle}" />

    <Controls:AddressControl x:Name="grdAdddress" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>

</Grid>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main trouble here is that `ColumnDefinition.ActualWidth` is not a `DependencyProperty` and will not update if you bind to it.

I assume you do not only want to set yellow to red, but synchronize to the larger width. If your situation is reasonably static (no changes to first column width after initial display), you can work with this:

In UserControl:

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition x:Name="Col1" Width="Auto"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

Code behind of UserControl:

```
public AddressControl()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.Loaded += AddressControl_Loaded;
}

void AddressControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var parentGrid = this.Parent as Grid;
    if (parentGrid != null)
    {
        var width = Math.Max(this.Col1.ActualWidth, parentGrid.ColumnDefinitions[0].ActualWidth);

        this.Col1.Width = new GridLength(width);
        parentGrid.ColumnDefinitions[0].Width = new GridLength(width);
    }
}
```

For more dynamic situations, you'd have to handle `SizeChanged` events.

Comment: great, as you said it gave me a temporary solution, i need to handle it manually on sizechanged. But also when i place the address control in some other column  i need to handle manually

Answer (score 1):

Trying to make a dependency property in control and bind it isn't going to work as adabyron said. His solution seems ok.

Comment: I appreciate your assent, but this is not an answer to the question. Once you have 50 points you'll be able to leave comments on existing answers, which this should be.